# Using JNA To set a Windows Z Position

Tags: java, winapi, jna, user32

I am trying to create a RainMeter-like application in Java with a few specific differences.  I want to grab a JavaFX window and move it behind the Icons on the desktop to set it to a Widget-like state.  I have managed to get my hands on the JNA library and even followed through with creating a User32 interface (though this was a walk through so I don't completely understand what its doing I do get the gist...), but as I am a novice Java developer I do not know what to do from here.  I have never dealt with Native API's and cannot find hardly any examples (It almost seems like this is not a common practice).

What I have managed to do so far:

```
public interface User32 extends Library {
    User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary((Platform.isWindows() ? "user32" : "c"), User32.class);
}
```

I do not know how to proceed as I have never needed to use the Platforms API so any code I do look at looks like gibberish to me.  If someone could point me to an IDIOTs guide or write an example with what they are doing I would greatly appreciate it! :)

LINKS I have found and referenced so far:

---

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx

https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/www/GettingStarted.md

[Can't set always-on-top for external applications in Java / C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21183994/cant-set-always-on-top-for-external-applications-in-java-c)

Comment: *Disclaimer: My understanding is very basic*, but as I understand it, the Desktop is "window" in of itself (like a "root" window), this might have changed since XP, but that was my basic understanding, so I don't think you can use this to get your window between the "desktop" and the icons, as the icons reside inside the desktop "window" ... how you would solve it I'm not sure, but it might give you a jumping off point for further investigation

Comment: The Windows Desktop is really a [List View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774737.aspx) control. To get in between the background and the icons requires, that you get inside the control. It's not just as simple as placing a window at the correct Z-position. Previously, there was Active Desktop (up to Windows XP) that allowed you to use HTML (and JavaScript) as the desktop background. But that's history, just like the Windows Sidebar and Gadgets (up to Windows 7).

Comment: Ok, so its sounding like its not really possible... so how about this, a similar result would be to get the opposite effect of "keep on top"... is there a way to force a window to be behind all other windows and stay there? Not behind the icons but that appears to be in the desktop because it never is on top of other windows...